# Unicode character ✰ (U+2730) not set up for use with LaTeX

Tags: compiling, texstudio, texmaker, unicode, ubuntu

I faced the error "Unicode character ✰ (U+2730) not set up for use with LaTeX." in my latex document. However, I didn't find the "shadowed star" in my code even though I didn't write it.
How may I find it to delete or how may I solve this error, please!

Note: I am running it on Ubuntu 20.04 operating system and with TeXStudio editor and TeXMaker editor.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Welcome to tex,sx.

Comment: Add `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2730}{HERE-HERE-HERE!}` to your document and then look where the HERE appears.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thaaaaank you for your answer. It was very helpful. The error is gone. However, the text "HERE-HERE-HERE!" didn't appear in the document

Comment: If it's not in your document, is it possible it's being inserted by a package you're using. What are you loading?

Answer (score 2):

Using `xelatex` or `lualatex`, just use a main font with the glyph:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{FreeSerif}
\begin{document}
Hello ✰
\end{document}
```

Or only for the symbols:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newfontfamily{\stars}{FreeSerif}[Scale=1.5,Color=blue]
\begin{document}
 Hello {\stars ✩ ✰ ✱ ✲} stars !!
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

For `pdflatex`, another solution is `\FiveStarShadow{}`  provided  by the package `bbding`.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pifont}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2730}{\ding{80}}
\begin{document}
✰
\end{document}
```