# Error when including Hebrew characters in R markdown

Tags: r, hebrew, markdown

I'm trying to create PDF report with R markdown.
The report includes some Hebrew names as part of a table.

When kniting the R markdown file, I get:

```
! LaTeX Error: Unicode character מ (U+05DE)
               not set up for use with LaTeX
```

I'm using R studio, and have MikTex 4.7.
Also installed culmus Hebrew fonts (though Hebrew is not listed in the MikTex languages).

How can this be corrected so Hebrew characters are compiled correctly?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Probably you have to add some commands to the preamble of the generated document to setup the Hebrew Unicode characters. I'm not sure which tool chain you use; maybe https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/latex-preamble.html helps. In the preamble, you have to add those commands that you would also use to typeset a LaTeX document directly (that contains Hebrew).

Comment: Search on this site "not set up for use with LaTeX" and you will see many answers to deal with this problem, like   [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/644789/unicode-character-u2730-not-set-up-for-use-with-latex).